# Problems with the click mobile hybrid replaced

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I am having issues with the click on mobile, I am scheduling in Intel XDK, using the cordova as program to understand native commands in my application.

My problem happens when I am by clicking some inputs or also when i redireciono for any page. To do some of the activities mentioned above, the application directs the focus for the select closest, however this happens only when the select exists at the same location where there was the click initial.

This also occurs when has any input field and select at low, because when you click in inputs I play the field with focus to the top of the page. I suspected that is by the question of how quickly the click, when the click exits, he is already with the screen loaded and the program considers that the click is on to select.

I would like you to help him because he had already tried some things as put all the pages that are not accessible to the left with the idea of remedy part of the problem, but I had no sucess.

I do not know which code to add, because this happens in general with application, for this reason I do not know which code place. If necessary make the requests that i editarei the question with the codes.

Comment: Can you give us some code to work with?

Comment: Which part of the code you want to ?

Comment: So the mobile web application is having issues when you are manipulating user input or navigating away.  Ok.  So whats wrong?  It is not doing what you want, what is it suppose to do?  When you add breakpoints are your functions being called which you want?

Comment: The problem occurs when I install the Mobile application on your Smartphone, the system of Cordova together with ionic, to give a activate_page() he withdraws the page whose I am passing by parameter the property hidden and so the page becomes visible. I wish the click to go to a page or clicking on an input it captures the click in the right place, for this I am thinking that is related to the speed of the click.

Comment: I am studying on the difference in touch to click, however not i have found nothing that satisfies my doubts and my problem in itself.

Comment: It seems that it is something of a multiple touch, because when he receives the event click it propagates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a click function in your app, then you have to take care of two problems:

1. Initialize the click function only once.
   A good way to prevent multiple initializations is to use the off-function:

```js
$(".myButton").off().on("click", function(){
   // Your button logic here
});
```

2. Prevent the click event for bubbling up in the DOM. Use this code to prevent it:

```js
$(".myButton").off().on("click", function(){
   event.stopPropagation();
   event.preventDefault();
   // Your button logic here
    });
```

A small tip: To have a better user experience, use tap instead of click.